# Localize key names

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, localization, key

I have a multi-language WinForms application where I let the user choose his own hotkeys. But I don't know how to correctly display the name of the keys he defines (in tooltips or in the form where to define them), in the user language. For now, I just display the raw name of the `System.Windows.Forms.Keys` bound, but things like "Oem7" or "OemOpenBrackets" are not very user friendly, especially when the key for this last one is actually the closing bracket on my french keyboard...

If found here that TypeConverter can do something like this, but it only works for a few keys (e.g. Delete is fine), not all (even numpad or space aren't handled).

So, is there anything built-in in the .NET framework or may I have to create my own translations for each key and each language I want to use?

Comment: Isn't it that what you have to do is to obtain Unicode character based on Key Code? Just an idea

Comment: If the key is a character yes ("OemOpenBrackets" would be ")" in french), but for other special keys like Enter, Shift, Escape, etc. I need their name.

Comment: Aren't Enter, Shift and Escape are universal? I think, you make mistake. I mean, use "KeyCode", not key name.

Comment: If there were only those basics it wouldn't be a great problem, but do you know which key matches "Oem5" on your keyboard? Imagine if game developpers would display such names on the binding screen, it would be a bit horrible for the player...